# Overriding a configuration property from inside the parent project in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

I have the following SpringBoot project structure ..

`dependencyProject` is packaged as a .jar and contains property configuration files:

```
.
└── dependencyProject
    └── src
        └── main
            └── resources
                ├── application-dev.yml
                └── application.yml
```

`application-dev.yml` contains

```
app-configuration.org.app.shell: true
```

Then `mainProject` consumes `dependencyProject` i.e `dependencyProject` is on the classpath.

```
.
├── config
│   └── application.yml
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── Main.java
```

`application.yml` contains

```
app-configuration.org.app.shell: false
```

By default my app runs in `dev` profile.

When I run the app, the value for `app-configuration.org.app.shell` is `true`.

Why is it not using the value obtained from `application.yml`, inside the main/root project?

Is there a way I can override the property value from inside my main project, without having to edit the version inside the jar project?

Comment: Is there a default value set in the dependency module ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it not using the value obtained from application.yml, inside the main/root project?

Spring loads configuration properties in the following order:

```
1. Application properties packaged inside your jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
2. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
3. Application properties outside of your packaged jar (application.properties and YAML variants).
4. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).
```

Source: [Spring-boot. Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

Your properties in `dev` profile are loaded later and override the value.

> Is there a way I can override the property value from inside my main project, without having to edit the version inside the jar project?

You probably can do some workaround but be aware that this could result in reverse confusion for others (e.g. why my profile-specific properties do not override those defined in application properties as Spring claims to be)

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understood your question correctly, you can override the value using an environment variable. Like this,

```
-Dapp-configuration.org.app.shell=false
```